# Change the profile picture or image in react native

Tags: react-native

For changing the profile picture in react native, searched and read couple of sites. All of them were using react-native-image-picker. Tried twice using the library (react-native-image-picked) but encountered problem both time.

Error message is "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.". Kindly suggest to resolve the issue.

Comment: react-native-image-picker is the most suitable package for picking images and it works fine. If you have some issues with package please visit the issue page https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues

Comment: Thank you, Akila Devinda. Problem fixed by using react-native-image-crop-picker. Link is https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/example/app.js